# Как передать значение из lable в контролер

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

У меня есть контролер в нем метод "submitTask"

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

 @PostMapping("submitTask")
    public String submitTask(@RequestParam("idTask") String idTask,
                             Model model) {
  
        System.out.println(idTask);
        return "main";

}
```

И есть html

```
<form th:action="@{/submitTask}" method="post" >
    <div th:each="task : ${tasks}">    
        <label th:text="${task.id}">...</label>           
        <button type="submit">Завершить</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Как я могу получить значение лейбла в контролер?

Comment: эээээм...
никак! это лейбл...зачем тебе передавать что-то из него? поставь там input[type=hidden] и передай через него

Comment: @МихаилРебров Спасибо большое